# (new title) jpa merge not working well with bidirectional java relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cycle, cascade

**Problem was partially solved, raising new, more specific question. I suggest skipping the old content.**

*Previous title: "Cascade merge overlapping object trees in jpa":*

> *I have multiple trees of jpa entities. The relation parent<->child is bidirectional in java. Both parent and child
>   have reference to each other. The relation on database side is always
>   from child to parent, no jointables. The trees overlap each other.
>   There are cycles (in the sum of trees). I want to merge all
>   objects calling EntityManager.merge() on trees' roots. I tried
>   setting CascadeType.ALL on all relations on parents' sides. The result
>   is always as follows, no matter what is the order of roots to merge:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property
>   references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before
>   current operation: com.example.Foo1 -> com.example.Foo2*
>
> *What should I do to make it right?*

**New question (UPDATE):**

The cause is indeed bidirectional java relation not being cascaded well if using merge (works well for persist). Thus I want to ask a new, more specific question based on the following scenario:

Class A:

```
    @Entity
    class A {
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.All)
            List<B> bs;
            //...
    }
```

Class B:

```
    @Entity
    class B {
            @ManyToOne
            A a;
            //...
    }
```

execution:

```
            A a = new A();
            B b = new B();

            a.setBs(Arrays.asList(new B[]{b});
            b.setA(a);

            //em.persist(a) works as desired. 
            //Probably because inserts are postponed to the end of transaction.

            em.merge(a); //throws exception:
```

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation: com.example.B -> com.example.A*

If I understand correctly, `a` being merged, and having cascade on, tries to execute merge on his child `b`, before his own merge. But the correct order of database operation is first insert `a` then insert `b`.

I solved the problem resigning from the cascade. But can we make cascade work here? Seems physically possible for me.

Comment: Can you show us your jpa mappings?

Comment: Sorry, there is just too much of it to show

Comment: Sorry, but it's the only way we can easily help you ...

Comment: I have a feeling it is about cascade not working with bidirectional references and I repaired some of such situations. Can't confirm it completely solves the problem yet.